# Extracting values from multiple scope inside an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a twitter bot that takes input of someone that DM's my account, and then will output the received DM's into tweet. I'm using twit package from npm. The question is, how do you extract the id's from the output, and then use the id's in another function in order to post the tweet, using? (note that I'm currently using console.log as the tweet for now).

> Input command to check the direct messages

```
var listMsg = T.get('direct_messages/events/list', {
    count: '50'
    }, function(data, response) {
        console.log(response)
```

> Output in terminal (the multiple scope inside the events array)

```
{
  events: [
    {
      type: 'message_create',
      id: '1275746339314216965', //take this
      created_timestamp: '1592996604170',
      message_create: [Object]
    },
    {
      type: 'message_create',
      id: '1274664227584671750', //and this
      created_timestamp: '1592738608629',
      message_create: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

> Getting the content of a direct message

```
var getMsg = T.get('direct_messages/events/show', {
    id:'1274664227584671750' //put it to this
    }, function(data, response) {
       //console.log(response)
            let dm = response.event.message_create.message_data
            console.log(dm) //and print the message here
```

> The content of the direct message

```
{
  text: 'Abcd',
  entities: { hashtags: [], symbols: [], user_mentions: [], urls: [] }
}
```

I want to get the id's as a let just like in the third code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the map array function to transform the object like this

`events.map( function(e) { return e.id})` or you can use es6 syntax `events.map(e=> e.id)`

both would return an array like this

`["1275746339314216965", "1274664227584671750"]`

These could be joined into into a string like so

`events.map(e=> e.id).join(",")`

returning

`"1275746339314216965,1274664227584671750"`

`map()` is a great function try playing around with `map` `reduce` and `filter` to really improve your programming. There's a great article on them here https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d

Of course you could do also use a good old fashioned for loop, but think that would be a bit verbose and unnecessary (the software equivalent of making your own hammer)

e.g.

```js
var ids = []
for(var event of events) {
  ids.push(event.id) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved me. Do you have any more recommended function in JS?

Comment: `every()`, `some()` and `includes()` are some other useful array functions, they are similar to `All()`, `Any()`, `Contains()` in C# Linq respectively, where as map, filter and reduce are equivalent to `Select()`, `Find()` and `Aggregate()` respectively. For the full list of all the array list have a look here on the side, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array